# Connecting Access Database to Java Netbeans

Tags: java, database, ms-access, netbeans

I am currently a Information System Student which has been given a programming final year coursework to complete. I am not in any way good at programming and depend on google and class notes to perform the simplest of tasks.

I was given the task to design a simple Supermarket application which has 10 items. The user clicks on an item and selects the amount/weight which then gets added to a total at a text box at the bottom. Each item when clicked gets added to the sum.

I have already done as much as my poor skills can do but i have two errors.

1. I manually wrote in the 10 items within the program. They need to be connected through an access database. I have googled this method and found that Netbeans does help a lot with this function and usually only one line is needed such as

   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver  (*.mdb)};Dbq=d:\test.mdb");

I have no clue how to connect the database or how to extract or use the information while it is connected to Netbeans.

1. I had initially, to start, programmed it in such a way that only one item could be selected at a time. The rest would go blank and only the sum of the item clicked would appear in the box below. For the life of me, I cant figure out how to get the items to add when clicked. I am pretty sure it is a simple SUM function but I am just so confused.

Any advice would be appreciated. Please explain as simply as possible. I know the basics but my capabilities barely stretch as far as the "Hello World" program lol

---

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Supermarket1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
Connection conn = null;


JButton oneP, twoP, fiveP, tenP, twentyP, fiftyP, onePound, twoPounds, fivePounds,            tenPounds, twentyPounds, fiftyPounds, beans, flakes, sugar, tea, coffee, bread, sausage,   egg, milk, potato;
JLabel messLabel = new JLabel("Amount to pay:  ");
JTextField message = new JTextField(10);
int amount = 0; // payment in pence
DecimalFormat pounds = new DecimalFormat("£0.00");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Supermarket1 c = new Supermarket1();
    c.setTitle("Supermarket payment simulator");
    c.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    c.setSize(500, 200);
    c.setVisible(true);
}

Supermarket1() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    oneP = new JButton("1p"); oneP.addActionListener(this);
    twoP = new JButton("2p"); twoP.addActionListener(this);
    fiveP = new JButton("5p"); fiveP.addActionListener(this);
    tenP = new JButton("10p"); tenP.addActionListener(this);
    twentyP = new JButton("20p"); twentyP.addActionListener(this);
    fiftyP = new JButton("50p"); fiftyP.addActionListener(this);
    onePound = new JButton("£1"); onePound.addActionListener(this);
    twoPounds = new JButton("£2"); twoPounds.addActionListener(this);
    fivePounds = new JButton("£5"); fivePounds.addActionListener(this);
    tenPounds = new JButton("£10"); tenPounds.addActionListener(this);
    twentyPounds = new JButton("£20"); twentyPounds.addActionListener(this);
    fiftyPounds = new JButton("£50"); fiftyPounds.addActionListener(this);
    beans = new JButton("Baked Beans"); beans.addActionListener(this);
    flakes = new JButton("Corn Flakes"); flakes.addActionListener(this);
    sugar = new JButton("Sugar"); sugar.addActionListener(this);
    tea = new JButton("Tea Bags"); tea.addActionListener(this);
    coffee = new JButton("Instant Coffee"); coffee.addActionListener(this);
    bread = new JButton("Bread"); bread.addActionListener(this);
    sausage = new JButton("Sausage"); sausage.addActionListener(this);
    egg = new JButton("Egg"); egg.addActionListener(this);
    milk = new JButton("Milk"); milk.addActionListener(this);
    potato = new JButton("Potatoes"); potato.addActionListener(this);

    rightButtons();

    JPanel leftSide = new JPanel();
    leftSide.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    leftSide.add(oneP);
    leftSide.add(twoP);
    leftSide.add(fiveP);
    leftSide.add(tenP);
    leftSide.add(twentyP);
    leftSide.add(fiftyP);
    leftSide.add(onePound);
    leftSide.add(twoPounds);
    leftSide.add(fivePounds);
    leftSide.add(tenPounds);
    leftSide.add(twentyPounds);
    leftSide.add(fiftyPounds);
    add("West", leftSide);

    JPanel rightSide = new JPanel();
    rightSide.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));
    rightSide.add(beans);
    rightSide.add(flakes);
    rightSide.add(sugar);
    rightSide.add(tea);
    rightSide.add(coffee);
    rightSide.add(bread);
    rightSide.add(sausage);
    rightSide.add(egg);
    rightSide.add(milk);
    rightSide.add(potato);
    add("East", rightSide);

    JPanel middle = new JPanel();
    middle.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    middle.add(messLabel);
    message.setEditable(false);
    middle.add(message);
    add("Center", middle);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == beans) { amount = 35; leftButtons(); }
    if (e.getSource() == flakes) { amount = 100; leftButtons(); }
    if (e.getSource() == sugar) { amount = 50; leftButtons(); }
    if (e.getSource() == tea) { amount = 115; leftButtons(); }
    if (e.getSource() == coffee) { amount = 250; leftButtons(); }
    if (e.getSource() == bread) { amount = 50; leftButtons(); }
    if (e.getSource() == sausage) { amount = 130; leftButtons(); }
    if (e.getSource() == egg) { amount = 75; leftButtons(); }
    if (e.getSource() == milk) { amount = 65; leftButtons(); }
    if (e.getSource() == potato) { amount = 125; leftButtons(); }
    if (e.getSource() == oneP) amount -= 1;
    if (e.getSource() == twoP) amount -= 2;
    if (e.getSource() == fiveP) amount -= 5;
    if (e.getSource() == tenP) amount -= 10;
    if (e.getSource() == twentyP) amount -= 20;
    if (e.getSource() == fiftyP) amount -= 50;
    if (e.getSource() == onePound) amount -= 100;
    if (e.getSource() == twoPounds) amount -= 200;
    if (e.getSource() == fivePounds) amount -= 500;
    if (e.getSource() == tenPounds) amount -= 1000;
    if (e.getSource() == twentyPounds) amount -= 2000;
    if (e.getSource() == fiftyPounds) amount -= 5000;

    if (amount > 0) message.setText(pounds.format(amount / 100.0));
    else {
        message.setText("");
        if (amount < 0) {
            int change = -amount;
            showMessageDialog(this, "Your change is "
                + pounds.format(change / 100.0)
                + coins(change),
                "Change", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            showMessageDialog(this, "Thank you",
                "Exact amount", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        rightButtons();
    }
}

// enable left buttons, disable right buttons
void leftButtons() {
    oneP.setEnabled(true);
    twoP.setEnabled(true);
    fiveP.setEnabled(true);
    tenP.setEnabled(true);
    twentyP.setEnabled(true);
    fiftyP.setEnabled(true);
    onePound.setEnabled(true);
    twoPounds.setEnabled(true);
    fivePounds.setEnabled(true);
    tenPounds.setEnabled(true);
    twentyPounds.setEnabled(true);
    fiftyPounds.setEnabled(true);
    beans.setEnabled(true);
    flakes.setEnabled(true);
    sugar.setEnabled(true);
    tea.setEnabled(true);
    coffee.setEnabled(true);
    bread.setEnabled(true);
    sausage.setEnabled(true);
    egg.setEnabled(true);
    milk.setEnabled(true);
    potato.setEnabled(true);
}

// enable right buttons, disable left buttons
void rightButtons() {
    oneP.setEnabled(false);
    twoP.setEnabled(false);
    fiveP.setEnabled(false);
    tenP.setEnabled(false);
    twentyP.setEnabled(false);
    fiftyP.setEnabled(false);
    onePound.setEnabled(false);
    twoPounds.setEnabled(false);
    fivePounds.setEnabled(false);
    tenPounds.setEnabled(false);
    twentyPounds.setEnabled(false);
    fiftyPounds.setEnabled(false);
    beans.setEnabled(true);
    flakes.setEnabled(true);
    sugar.setEnabled(true);
    tea.setEnabled(true);
    coffee.setEnabled(true);
    bread.setEnabled(true);
    sausage.setEnabled(true);
    egg.setEnabled(true);
    milk.setEnabled(true);
    potato.setEnabled(true);
}

String coins(int change) {
    String answer = ":";
    if (change >= 5000) {
        answer += "\nOne £50 note";
        change -= 5000;
    }
    if (change >= 4000) {
        answer += "\nTwo £20 notes";
        change -= 4000;
    }
    if (change >= 2000) {
        answer += "\nOne £20 note";
        change -= 2000;
    }
    if (change >= 1000) {
        answer += "\nOne £10 note";
        change -= 1000;
    }
    if (change >= 500) {
        answer += "\nOne £5 note";
        change -= 500;
    }
    if (change >= 400) {
        answer += "\nTwo £2 coin";
        change -= 400;
    }
    if (change >= 200) {
        answer += "\nOne £2 coin";
        change -= 200;
    }
    if (change >= 100) {
        answer += "\nOne £1 coin";
        change -= 100;
    }
    if (change >= 50) {
        answer += "\nOne 50p coin";
        change -= 50;
    }
    if (change >= 40) {
        answer += "\nTwo 20p coins";
        change -= 40;
    }
    if (change >= 20) {
        answer += "\nOne 20p coin";
        change -= 20;
    }
    if (change >= 10) {
        answer += "\nOne 10p coin";
        change -= 10;
    }
    if (change >= 5) {
        answer += "\nOne 5p coin";
        change -= 5;
    }
    if (change >= 4) {
        answer += "\nTwo 2p coin";
        change -= 4;
    }
    if (change >= 2) {
        answer += "\nOne 2p coin";
        change -= 2;
    }
    if (change >= 1) {
        answer += "\nOne 1p coin";
        change -= 1;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you have so far? Show some code. We don't know anything about your environment (web app, desktop app, Netbeans RCP, ...)

Comment: As this is a final year coursework your profs assume that your skill set - enhanced with some self study - is a sufficient basis to realize this task.  So, get started on that self study part, create some code and come back once you have specific questions and some code to prove the effort you put in.  Wrt that self study thing: duffymo's suggestion is an excellent choice, also have a look at the other tutorials on that site. Java is hardly an esoteric technology, tutorials are everywhere, even for someone who "depends on google and class notes to perform the simplest of tasks"

Comment: Heres what I have done so far.....

Comment: e.g. this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191420/java-ms-access-and-jdbc-connectivity

Comment: Ok thanks for all the links, Im actually at work so Ill have to try it when I get home. I guess no going out tonight :( Thanks for all your help.... Im sure Ill have more questions later....

Comment: Ishikawa.... Now this is going to sound silly but Im sure I did try some code and eventually got a message (I cant remember where) that showed that my Java code was connected to my database (I think) but I guess thats where I was stuck.... What do I do with all the data I already have in my Java code and how do I use the data from the database?

Comment: I know I must sound so silly, especially being a computer science student but..... If you dont ask you will never learn.... :s

Comment: Too much code, dude.  You've got to learn how to write less of it.

Comment: Too much code? wow I was under the impression I needed to write more..... Ill try and cut some down I guess.....

Comment: Ok so finally got the database connected!!! Yay! and used the select query to retrieve data from the table!    Ok now the problem is adding the prices of each item, when clicked, to the total. No clue what Im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is just an IDE; you don't connect anything to NetBeans.

Your Java code is what is connecting to the Access database.

What you're doing is making a JDBC connection.  I'd recommend a [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/).

It sounds like you're committing a classic student mistake: poor decomposition.

You solve big problems by breaking them into smaller ones that you can handle.

You've got a user interface, database access, and your application all going on here.  I'd recommend that you start with the database acces first.  Write one Java object that handles what you need.  Test it thoroughly and then use it to take the next step with your user interface.

Comment: Dave and Deffymo thank you so much for your answers..... Dave I will try and upload some code now and Duffy I will check out that tutorial now.....I did look at a few tutorials which told me to use SQL which I was trying to do, spend the whole week trying to do it, only to learn that my course specifications specifically said to not use Sql.... :(

Comment: Your are profoundly confused.  You'll be using SQL when you query Access.  You don't need a few tutorials for JDBC, just the one I gave you.  You need to learn SQL, too.

Comment: Duffymo thanks for all your help, At work so will attempt it when I get home using your tutorials and links. Expect more silly questions later when I get home lol Thanks again

Comment: JPA?  Are you kidding me?  This person just admitted that their skills are at a "Hello World" level.  I think it's criminal to suggest that a student who can't see how to write a SELECT query should use JPA.

Comment: Ok got the database connected and retrieving data from the table but now I need to write code to make every transaction be stored in a separate table on the same database. Then for example at the end of a day, the total transaction list can be printed.... Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: No, this is wrong.  You don't want every transaction stored in a separate table.  You want a TRANSACTION table with multiple rows in it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code from:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=d:\test.mdb");
```

To using a double backslash (`\\`)

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=d:\\test.mdb");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StudentFunctions  implements StudentInterface
{
    String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=//////URL where your database is located//////";

    String query = "";

    Connection conn;
    Statement s;

@Override
public boolean AddStudent(String name, String age, String contact, String program) {
 try {
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
       Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        query ="insert into StudentRecord([stname],[age],[contact],[program])values('"+name+"','"+age+"','"+contact+"','"+program+"')";

        if(s.executeUpdate(query) > 0)
        {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record successfully add in database");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
     Logger.getLogger(StudentFunctions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

This is code in which I connected access to my project of student record, hope it might help you.